# E-Mail Reminder Based On Date Columns In SharePoint 365 Online List

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, email, notifications, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have an online list that has a lots of columns. Columns A,B,C and D are in date format. Date in column D is always populated, but dates that are in A, B and C should be entered later on, before the date in D. I need a workflow that sends out an e-mail if dates are in A, B and C are not populated two weeks before the date in D. If any of columns of A, B and C are empty e-mail should let person know that date in D is approaching. I use SharePoint 365.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a workflow using the following steps:

[image]

Use the “set workflow available” action to check if the date column is empty using “string” type.

[image]

Comment: Is this workflow configuration can be found in SharePoint 365?

Comment: Yes, you can open SharePoint Online site in SharePoint Designer, create a workflow in SharePoint 2010/2013 workflow platform and associate with the relevant list. And the actions I mentioned above.